# How do I print a 2D array that holds values structured in a toString()?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return, tostring

My problem so far is that I have created an array that holds six values. Each value is equal to a "profile" that calls for the creation of an object instance(?) (I apologize for butchering everything right now but bear with me). How do I print this array and get the printed results put into a variable so I can 'return' it?

**edit** Okay to clarify. I want to know how to print the applicant[] array in the code below. However, I also want to put it in a single variable, a variable that allows me to return it to the method so I can call it to another class. As in how do I make either the printed array or the array itself call-able from another class. What do I need to change or erase.

**Notes on the following code:**

*I understand the method is declared with 'void', I just did that so it could compile. (What should I put on there instead?)

*The students calls from a constructor in another class called Applicaiton

*When these new object instances(?) it is done through a toString()

*The class below, as it exists, perfectly compiles.

*Please answer as simply as possible if you can, and thank you so much for the consideration.

public class Profiles

{

```
public void applicantProfiles()
{

    Application student1 = new Application("Blair", "C", "Bass", "12345 Rainbow Road", "06010 Bristol, CO", "11/15/97", "Constance Billard School for Girls", 2380, 33, 4.0, 61681, 234400.81, false, false, false);
    Application student2 = new Application("Daniel", "R", "Humphrey", "36191 79th Street", "10024 New York, NY", "4/20/96", "St. Jude's School for Boys", 1800, 31, 3.6, 48347, 26489, false, true, true);
    Application student3 = new Application("Charlie", "L", "Trout", "21910 Devonshire", "91303 Northridge, CA", "7/27/97", "Harvard-Westlake", 2100, 28, 3.9, 61681, 41000, true, false, true);
    Application student4 = new Application("Damascus", "L", "Roberto", "667 Ofarrel Street", "94109 San Francisco, CA", "2/14/97", "Galileo Academy of Science and Technology", 2382, 27, 3.8, 61681, 39678, false, false, true);
    Application student5 = new Application("Sofia", "M", "Montrone", "24980 Oscar Lane", "32468 Willow Park, OR", "11/31/95", "Bayview High School", 2400, 30, 3.9, 48347, 99846.22, true, true, false);
    Application student6 = new Application();

    Application[] applicant;
    applicant = new Application[6]; 
    applicant[0] = student1;
    applicant[1] = student2;
    applicant[2] = student3;
    applicant[3] = student4;
    applicant[4] = student5;
    applicant[5] = student6;

    for (int index = 0; index < applicant.length; index++)
    {
        System.out.println(applicant[index]);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: So what do you want exactly?
Does the Syso statement at the moment print out the right way? Did you implement a toString() method in you Application class? And what would you like to return? A string with all the students data?

Comment: You need to re-read and analize your question one more time. It is impossible to understand

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing that you'll want to do is make a String with said array that you "want to print out". In python you can print and return lists, yet not in Java. The easiest way to do this is:

```
String value = "[" + value1 + ", " + value2 + ", " ... + valuen + "]";
```

You can automate this with a for loop if the return size changes. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to override the toString() method in your Application class and print out the results structured in whatever way you want them to be. When you call System.out.println(some_object), the toString() method declared for that object is called. For example, do the following in your Application class.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String printString = "First name = " + this.firstName + ", Last name = " + this.lastName;
    // I've shown this just for first name and last name structured in a very simple manner
    // You will have to adjust it to your needs
    return printString; // This is what will be printed
}
```

The toString() method belongs to the Object class and hence every class that you create will automatically inherit this method. Overriding it is left up to you.

Comment: Still his question is not clear. He does not say if he overrides the toString() method and how he wants to return the whole array

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `void` in your function, you should have `String`, and put this at the end of your function instead of the for-loop:

```
String ret = Arrays.deepToString(applicant);
return ret;
```

You will still need a `toString()` method in `Applicant` as described by Sunil.